# How to check contents of a column in a CSV file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing a small app where the user uploads a csv file to the document folder in the app through iTunes. I am using the following code, but it checks only the first column in first row. Its not checking the second rows column. My csv file contains 2 rows and 4 columns each. First column is a number. The user will type this number in a text box and click a button to check whether the number is in csv file. The following function is the one I am using

```
-(void)CheckEntry //this function checks the example.csv file
{
    NSArray *DocumentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *DocumentDirectory = [DocumentPath objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *FullPath = [DocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.csv"]];

    NSString * pstrCSVFile= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:FullPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSArray * paRowsOfCSVFile= [pstrCSVFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];

    NSArray *paColumnsOfRow;
    NSString *pstrFirstColumn;
    for(NSString * pstrRow in paRowsOfCSVFile)
    {
        paColumnsOfRow= [pstrRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        pstrFirstColumn= [paColumnsOfRow objectAtIndex:0];

        if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:GWIDText.text] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The record was found"];
            UIAlertView *alertingFileName = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:msg message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertingFileName show];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Found"];
            UIAlertView *alertingFileName = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:msg message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertingFileName show];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you logged paRowsOfCSVFile.count to see if it's 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] instead of componentsSeparatedByString: and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show an alert view inside a loop. So you end up trying to show as many alert views as there are rows. That is unlikely what you want. Your requirement is unclear. Do you want to check all columns of all rows, just the first column of all rows, or simply find the first match and stop?

Create a BOOL variable just before the loop. Something like `BOOL found = NO;`. Then in the loop, set the variable to YES when you find a match. Then, after the loop, show the proper alert based on the `found` variable. The exact solution really depends on your true intent here.

Comment: Here are the clear requirements. I upload a csv file to the document folder of the app. Now I give a text box and a button to the user. User will enter a number and press the button. Now the code has to check first columns of all the rows and display the message that the user was found.

Comment: OK, then what I posted is correct. You simply want to scan every row looking for a match. So show the alert after the loop based on the flag. If you only care about the first match, then you can break out of the loop as soon as a match is found. IF you want to count the matches and tell the user how many matches there were, change the flag to an integer and increment for each match. Either way don't show any alert inside the loop. Do it after the loop.

Comment: Ok, I did exactly as you said. I took out the alert, and placed it out side of the loop. Now, what I do in the loop is just set found=1 or 0. Its still not working. The first row first column number checks out but not the second row first column.

Comment: Only set 'found' to YES on a match. Don't set it to NO on a mismatch. You don't care about mismatches, only matches. So after the loop, you want to know - "was any match found at all?".

Comment: That logic is sound. You may have other issues. Have you run this in the debugger and stepped through the iteration? Have you verified that  you really have two rows and that each row is really split into the 4 columns? Have you verified that GWIDText isn't nil?

Comment: @G-Man, I'll ask again, have you logged paRowsOfCSVFile.count to see if it's 2?

Comment: OK, the count is 1. Thats what I don't understand. I don't know why its not going after the first row. I am creating csv file by saving an excel file as csv file. this is a normal procedure and it worked for me before, but suddenly its not working. Can you try in your mac please?

Comment: Use your debugger. Does `ptrCSVFile` contain the full CSV file? Are lines really separated by \r\n or just \n or something else?

Comment: I think the problem is here NSArray *paRowsOfCSVFile= [pstrCSVFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; I tried both \r and \n and \r\n. But when i print pstrCSVFile, it shows in a single line